# Elementary set relations

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, filters

$\mathcal N(p)$ is a set of all neighborhoods of $p$.

Statement:

> A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is compact if and only if every filter on $X$ can be refined to a convergent filter (on $X$).

Proof:

> Suppose $(X, \tau)$ is compact. Given a filter $\Lambda$, notice that $\{\overline F: F \in \Lambda\}$ is a family of closed sets, the intersections of whose finite subfamilies are all non-empty. Therefore $\exists p \in \bigcap \{\overline F : F \in \Lambda \}.$ Put $\Lambda_1 = \{\text{all supersets of sets of the form } F \cap N : F \in \Lambda, N \in \mathcal N(p)\}.$
> Then $\Lambda_1$ is a filter on $X, \ \color{red}{\mathcal N(p), \Lambda \subseteq \Lambda_1}$ as required.

> Suppose $(X, \tau)$ is not compact. Then there is a family $\Gamma$ of closed subsets whose finite subfamilies all have non-empty intersections, and yet the entire family has empty intersection. Then $\Lambda$ = the collection of all supersets of finite intersections from $\Gamma$ is a filter on $X$. If, for some filter $\Lambda_1$, we had $\Lambda,\ \mathcal N(p) \subseteq \Lambda′$, then for all $N \in \mathcal N(p)$ and for all $F \in \Gamma, \ \color{blue}{N \cap F \neq \emptyset}$. Therefore $p \in \overline F = F \text{ for all } F \in \Gamma$ – contradiction.

How did they obtain the colored bits above?

My guess for the red one: $\mathcal N(p)$ is a filter and so $G = N_1 \cap N_2 \in \mathcal N(p)$ with $N_1, N_2 \in \mathcal N(p)$ and since $F$ is an element of an arbitrary filter, we can let $F = N_1$ or $F = N_2$ so that $G \in \Lambda_1.$ Similarly, $J \cap K \in \Lambda$ for some $J, K \in \Lambda$ where one of $J, K$ is a neighborhood of $p$?

Part in blue is true because every neighbourhood of $p$ contains a member of
the filter $\Lambda_1$ and since $\Lambda \subseteq \Lambda_1$, every neighbourhood of $p$ contains a member of $\Lambda$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to $\color{red}{\mathcal N(p), \Lambda \subseteq \Lambda_1}$:

Let $N$ be in $\mathcal{N}(p)$. So $N = X \cap N$ is a member of $\Lambda_1$ (it's a (superset of) a set of the form $F \cap N$ as in the definition of $\Lambda_1$ (note that $X \in \Lambda)$, as for all filters). This shows the inclusion.

That $\Lambda \subseteq \Lambda_1$ follows similarly, taking $N=X$ for any $F \in \Lambda$ as well.

As to $\color{blue}{N \cap F \neq \emptyset}$: this is just because all
$N$ are in $\Lambda'$ and so are all $F \in \Lambda \subseteq \Lambda'$, and members of the same filter have to intersect.

Comment: I see. I forgot(never realized) that $(1) \ p \in X, \ (2) \ X \in \Lambda$ meaning $N \subseteq X$ and $X$ is the largest(?) element in $\mathcal N(p)$.

Comment: @user934150 $X$ is a member of *any* filter on $X$ whether it be $\Lambda$ or $\mathcal{N}(p)$ etc. by the enlargement axiom; it's always the maximum element. That $p \in X$ is both obvious and irrelevant..